# update local entry in WSO2 ESB

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

How can I update local entry in WSO2 ESB through XML configuration or JavaScript?
When I update using set-property() it is not updating in local entry as a whole, it is just updating for that instance.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

yes thats right. when u create a property instance from a property saved somewhere in your registry and try a set property, it just change the value in that instance only. To save it in the original local instance first use a custom mediator and load the desired part in property instance then and create an output stream and store it like below

```
props.setProperty("key", "value");
props.store(out, null);
```

where out is outputstream instance.